# Why is the number value not initialized after the do while loop?

Tags: java, int

In my class the program is giving two errors at the integer: number. The program says that my integers could not be initialized. However, the variable: number is inputted by the user before the block of code that is giving the errors. What is wrong with my code?

```
package rollthedice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Odds {

    public void odds() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Numberone   object = new Numberone();
        Numbertwo   object2 = new Numbertwo();
        Numberthree object3 = new Numberthree();
        Numberfour  object4 = new Numberfour();
        Numberfive  object5 = new Numberfive();

        boolean error;
        boolean wholenumber;
        int number;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the game!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("On how many numbers do you want to bet?");
        System.out.println("These are the odds:");
        System.out.println("1 number:\t5.85");
        System.out.println("2 numbers:\t3.85");
        System.out.println("3 numbers:\t1.85");
        System.out.println("4 numbers:\t1.4");
        System.out.println("5 numbers:\t1.1");

        do{
            do{
                System.out.println("Pick a wole number between 1 and 5.");

                if(input.hasNextInt()){
                    number = input.nextInt();
                    wholenumber = true;
                }

                else{
                    System.out.println("You did not pick a whole number. Please try again. ");
                    wholenumber = false;
                    input.next();
                }

            }while(!(wholenumber));

            System.out.println();
            //these two values with the name number are not initialized
            error = 1 > number || number > 5;

            //this switch value is also not initialized
            switch(number){
            case 1: object.numberone();
            break;
            case 2: object2.numbertwo();
            break;
            case 3: object3.numberthree();
            break;
            case 4: object4.numberfour();
            break;
            case 5: object5.numberfive();
            default: 
                System.out.println("There are 6 sides on a dice. You cannot bet on all six sides. Please choose a number between 1 and 5.");
            }

        }while(error);

        input.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: @lurker OP is describing a compile error.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I was thinking it was a warning, not an error. I missed the later comment that it was an error (although sometimes beginners don't distinguish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it will always be initialized by that point of the code. The compiler is just not clever enough to make this inference because it relies on taking two logical steps - the if-statement and the do-while.

You can initialize it to some random value, safe in the knowledge that it will never actually be used.

```
int number = -1;
```

Comment: @StijnKrabbenborg Sure, happy to help

Comment: @StijnKrabbenborg you should click the Accept for this answer if it satisfied your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the compiler the variable number may not be initialized because it is initialized inside an `if` block and **not** inside the corresponding `else` block **too**.
To solve this put initialization code like this in `else`:

```
        else{
            number = -1;
            System.out.println("You did not pick a whole number. Please try again. ");
            wholenumber = false;
            input.next();
        }
```

You can change `-1` to `0` or whatever suits you.